# Meteor and twitter API

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter

I would like use twitter API for get my last tweet on my Meteor APP with "twit" module NPM.

That my code, but i get no data :

```
var Twit = require('twit');

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         'xxx', // API key
    consumer_secret:      'xxx', // API secret
    access_token:         'xxx',
    access_token_secret:  'xxx'
});

T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'hello since:2011-11-11', count: 100 }, function(err, data, response) {
    alert(data);
});
```

My access level on Twitter Developper :

Application Settings : Read and write
Access Token : Read and write

Do you have idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: you use the wrong endpoint

Comment: I've Error: Network error

Comment: @MarkUretsky Wrong endpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

I’m currently building an meteor app which should make use of the twitter API. Therefor I’m using the mrt:twit meteor package (https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/twit).

This is the part on server side which fetches the tweets into a local collection:

```
'getOldestTweets': function() {

        Twit = new TwitMaker({
            consumer_key: consumer_key,
            consumer_secret: consumer_secret,
            access_token: oauth_access_token,
            access_token_secret: oauth_access_token_secret
        });

        const OldestTweetsPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Twit.get('statuses/user_timeline', {
                count: 10,
                trim_user: false,
                exclude_replies: false,
                include_rts: true
            }, function(err, data, response) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        });

        OldestTweetsPromise
            .then(data => {
                if (collectionTweets.find().count() > 0) {
                    // there are already tweets, delete all from collection before inserting
                    collectionTweets.remove({});
                }
                // insert feteched data in collection
                const tweets = data;
                for (tweet in tweets) {
                    collectionTweets.insert(tweets[tweet]);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
}
```

I'm not sure how experienced you are and if you need more examples and details. Let me know.